# Mygica t119 DVB-T USB TV Stick on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dvb, dvb-t

I am using a [DVB-T USB TV Stick from mygica](http://mygica.com/html/TV_Tuner/20140802/62.html). I want to use it in Ubuntu 14.04
I tried with w_scan to detect DVB USB.

```
w_scan -c DE -X > channels.conf
w_scan version 20130331 (compiled for DVB API 5.10)
using settings for GERMANY
DVB aerial
DVB-T Europe
scan type TERRESTRIAL, channellist 4
output format czap/tzap/szap/xine
WARNING: could not guess your codepage. Falling back to 'UTF-8'
output charset 'UTF-8', use -C <charset> to override
Info: using DVB adapter auto detection.
main:3228: FATAL: ***** NO USEABLE TERRESTRIAL CARD FOUND. *****
Please check wether dvb driver is loaded and
verify that no dvb application (i.e. vdr) is running.
```

But it was not detecting the DVB-T stick. How can I get it to work?

Comment: hey, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @zuke yes, answer below is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

With `Kaffeine` player it worked instantly.

1. Open `Kaffeine`
2. `configure Television` settings --> `General Options`--> click "`updata scan data over internet`"
3. `configure Television` settings --> `Device1` --> selected source to "`autoscan`"
4. In `Television` --> `channels` --> `StartScan`